# Deploying a Visual Studio Excel 2007 Template

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, excel

I've created a project of type "Excel 2007 Template" in Visual Studio 2008, and I've deployed the project to a network share.

After I run the Studio-generated setup.exe, what do I do to open the template? Is there supposed to an entry in the Start Menu? Show up in Excel somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, found what I'm looking for.

In Visual Studio, I select "Publish Workbook". After entering a network path to house our code libraries and the Excel workbook, we distribute said workbook to our users. When the user opens up the workbook, it automatically installs the necessary DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\" folder inside the VS installation directory. This should contain the zipped folder of the template (needed files and the template file) and a ProjectTemplatesCache\ folder that should have the expanded folder (under the appropriate language / project type hierarchy).

Comment: Actually I want to find the template that I installed after deploying a "Excel 2007 Template" Visual Studio project.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, but the templates are all in the ProjectTemplatesCache and ItemTemplatesCache folders. Are you not able to find yours there?

Comment: I've already created a project with the template, that's not my issue. I need to deploy the compiled version of my project (it contains an Excel workbook and an associated DLL), but I don't know how to get it on a client's machine.

Comment: I think the confusion is between the actual project files the ones Mohit is talking about are the project templates for an excel VSTO workbook project, whereas Peder is talking about the template created by the project (workbook template) which is deployed and published via click once in VS. While not totally relevant to this question the locations are still interesting to those wanting to learn more about the way VS creates new projects.